# Drag formula 8 rows, but in a pattern that skips only 2 rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have this problem where I need to drag down a formula 8 rows in the A-column but it should only jump down 1 row in the E column. So `A2=751820,` A9=SF135200` and so on.

Can anyone help with a formula that is able to solve this or help me out in pointing me a direction that can? I see many people have the opposite problem, but is yet to find someone with a similar situation.

[image]

Comment: What is the formula you want to drag down?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on exactly what you're asking for?  From what I'm able to infer, here's a potential solution but might not be what you're looking for here:

Have `A2` set as `=E2`, then starting from `A9`, enter the formula: `=indirect("e"&rounddown((row()/8)+2))`

If you want a more elegant way to copy & paste / drag down column A, there's likely multiple ways to do so.  One way I can think of off the top of my head, is have a helper column somewhere that has blocks of 8 rows merged together and repeating down (e.g., `F3:F9`, `F10:...`, etc).  Then, have column A reference column F directly and sequentially (e.g., `A3` would have `=F3`, `A4` `=F4`, etc.).  I can't test in Excel at the moment, but the rows that do not line up with the first cell of each block should output a blank result; if not, use a conditional function or `IFERROR()` instead.

Comment: I have updated the problem and inserted a new screenshot. The item number column will be text or item numbers so a math function is not possible unfortunately. Hope this makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Why not?  You can still have the cell formatted as `number` data type, and apply the "Item_" string as a custom formatting prefix?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, column E contains the text values one below another, which must be distributed to every 7th row in column A. E is the input, A is the output.

We will use the INDEX function to reference the correct row number in E. The ROW function can be used to decide with we are at a 7th row (return INDEX) or not (return blank text). From A2:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-2,7)=0, INDEX($E:$E, INT((ROW()-2)/7)+2), "")
```

Comment: Hey! Mobus, This sounds about right. I have updated the photo to give a better understanding. Our website is in 7 languages (1=DK, 8=Sweden and so on). When I upload new products to our website it needs to be stacked on top of each other. Does this make sense? I have tried copy/pasting the formula into excel but it does not seem o work. We are way out of my current excel capabilities unfortunately..

Comment: The column numbers changed in your new example. Just change $F:$F to $E:$E in my formula. Put this formula into cell A2, the drag or copy and paste it all the way down in column A (for the blank and non-blank cells).

Comment: I updated the formula to column E, and also fixed a missing bracket. It should work now!

Comment: Also try this variation `=IF(MOD(ROW()-2,7)=0, INDEX($E:$E, INT((ROW()-2)/7)+2), A1)` which will not leave blank spaces, but actually duplicate the Item Number. This might be useful if for instance you need to use the Item Number for lookup functions in column C.

Comment: Hmm it says that there are too few arguments - which do I need to fill out? https://ibb.co/x3Nm65V

Comment: Ah, yes, you have a different localisation setting. You probably have to replace all the "," with ";" - I'm guessing. It may even be that you need to translate the english name functions to swedish? name functions, if your Excel / computer is set to a non-english language. But try the semi-colons first!

Comment: Omg thank you so much. Yes I was missing a couple of , converted to ; You have saved me for so much time! :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Kindly checkmark the solution so others may know the problem has been solved.